# <rich:dataList> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: dataList

Tags: jsf, richfaces, datalist

I have defined the name space xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich", but still getting an error saying " Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: dataList".

Here is the code :

```
<rich:dataList var="var" value="#{backingBean.value}" rows="5">
   <h:outputText value="#{var.property1}"/>
</rich:dataList>
```

Any idea why this is happening.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Have you included Richfaces jars in your WEB-INF lib folder?

Comment: @VikasV yes Vikas. I did include them and other rich components are working ie rich:panel, rich:autocomplete.

Comment: Where do you see the `<rich:dataList>` [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/) or [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dataList` component was deprecated in version 4.0.0.  From the [Migration Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.0.X/4.0.0.Milestone5/Migration_Guide/en-US/html_single/#sect-Migration_Guide-Deprecated_components_and_behaviors-richdataList_richdataDefinitionList_and_richdataOrderedList):

```
The functionality of the old <rich:dataList>, <rich:dataDefinitionList>, and 
<rich:dataOrderedList> components is now available through the 
<rich:list> component.
```

You should be able to use the `list` component.

Another way to confirm that a tag lib is available is to check the taglib definitions in the jar file that's providing them. For example, you should be able to reference the richfaces-components-ui.jar:META-INF/rich.taglib.xml file to see what tags and attributes are available for that specific version.